# Как посчитать количество вхождений символа в строку?

Tags: java, строки

Есть необходимость реализовать проверку на наличие нескольких запятых в строке. Т.е. можно использовать только одну запятую.

Но в целом достаточно узнать количество вхождений символа в строку. Остальное дописать не будет проблемой.

Какие есть способы это (посчитать количество вхождений символа) сделать?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Регулярка
2. Использовать `StringUtils.countMatches` из **[org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)**

   ```
   int occurrence = StringUtils.countMatches("a,b,c,d", ",");
   System.out.println(occurrence);
   ```
3. Использовать `string.split`

   ```
   String string = "a,b,c,d";
   String []splitArray = string.split("\\,");
   System.out.println("Запятых тут : " + (splitArray.length - 1) + " штук.");
   ```
4. ```
   String testString =  "a,b,c,d";
   int occurrencesCount = testString.length() - testString.replace(",", "").length();
   System.out.println(occurrencesCount);
   ```
5. Java8

   ```
   String testString =  "a,b,c,d";
   long occurrencesCount = testString.chars().filter(ch -> ch == ',').count();
   System.out.println(occurrencesCount);
   ```
6. Еще какой-нибудь способ

---

**UPD** нашел подобную тему на enSO: [How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/275944/6104996), несколько примеров  оттуда:

- Spring Framework

  ```
  int spring = org.springframework.util.StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(testString, ",");
  System.out.println("spring = " + spring);
  ```
- replaceAll

  ```
  int replaceAll = testString.replaceAll("[^,]", "").length();
  System.out.println("replaceAll = " + replaceAll);
  ```
- Java8

  ```
  long java8 = testString.codePoints().filter(ch -> ch == ',').count();
  System.out.println("java8 = " + java8);
  ```
- StringTokenizer

  ```
  int stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(" " +testString + " ", ",").countTokens()-1;
  System.out.println("stringTokenizer = " + stringTokenizer);
  ```

  Но в данном случае надо быть осторожным, так как, например, для строки a.b.c.d этот пример будет работать, а для строки a...b.c....d или ...a.b.c.d или a....b......c.....d... и т.д. — не будет. В итоге последовательность точек между каждой из букв посчитается лишь за один символ.

Comment: Огромное Спасибо за чудо инфу про StringUtils.countMatches!!! - просто идеально

Comment: Возможно, кстати, правильнее будет что-то вроде `occurrencesCount`.

Comment: @Regent да, определенно правильнее. поправил

Answer (score 4):

Если вопрос только в том, чтобы узнать больше ли одной запятой, то самый простой вариант такой:

```
String testString =  "a,b,c,d";
boolean isMoreThanOne = testString.indexOf(',') != testString.lastIndexOf(',');
System.out.println("More than one: " + isMoreThanOne);
```

Comment: "Самый простой" в каком плане и почему? И что вы подразумеваете под вариантом - сравнение индексов или использование `boolean` переменной?

Comment: Простой в плане что не создает побочных объектов, которые потом надо собирать сборщику мусора. Но с точки зрения читаемости, мне больше всего импонирует вариант с Java 8, сходу понятно что он делает.