# Сравнение символа с клавиатуры и из файла

Tags: java, scanner

Есть .txt файл, для простоты в нём только алфавит, без цифр и символов. Но с пробелами.
С клавиатуры ввожу букву, лезу в файл, считаю сколько раз моя буква встретилась, вывожу цифру на экран.
Вот мой код

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String symbol_GonaSearch = reader.readLine();  // эту букву буду искать

    char symbolI_Need = symbol_GonaSearch.charAt(0);  // присваиваю первый символ из строки с клавиатуры
    int numberOfSequence = 0;                                   // счётчик совпадений

    try(FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Roman\\Desktop\\AAA.txt"))  // достаю файл
       {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")                            // это не знаю зачем, эклипс попросила написать
    Scanner scanToTextFromFile = new Scanner(fileReader);  // через сканер что-бы работать с его методами

     while(scanToTextFromFile.nextLine() != null)          // до тех пор пока есть строки ...
         {
         String textStringForRewritteLines = scanToTextFromFile.next(); // строку записываю в новую стрингу
         for(int i = 0; i < textStringForRewritteLines.length(); i ++) // прохожусь по всем символам в строке
            {
             if(
                     textStringForRewritteLines.charAt(i) == symbolI_Need)  // если совпадают 
               { numberOfSequence ++;}              // счётчик плюс один
             }
         }
       }catch(NoSuchElementException seex) {         // а вот если что не так...
           System.out.print(StringStore.errorMessage + "\n"+  seex + "\n"); // пишем что именно
       }
    System.out.print(numberOfSequence);
```

Сообщение : java.util.NoSuchElementException
Ругается на строку String textStringForRewritteLines = scanToTextFromFile.next();
Подсажите пожалуйста, где я наговнокодил.
Т.Е. "где" я понимаю, но "что" не совсем.

Comment: Вот интересно, нахрена для такой задачи парсить текст на строки? чтобы потом мужественно преодолеть необходимость организовывать по ним итерацию? Для справки - количество заданных символов в тексте равно уменьшению длины этого текста после замены этого символа в нём на пустую строку.

Comment: @Akina, без парсинга текста на строки не получится, т.к. текст в файле может не влезть в String. А решений задачи нахождения количества вхождений подстроки в строке много (см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/725999/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83), и представленное решение вполне имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: @Akina только- что в String сохранил "Война и мир" , просто интересно было, каким должен быть текст что-бы он не влез в стрингу

Comment: @Tema_Bel *текст в файле может не влезть в String* А никто тогда не мешает читать файл чанками, заменять в каждом чанке, и дельты суммировать. *представленное решение вполне имеет право на жизнь* Очень забавно... раз текст не влезает в память, давайте в него ещё байтов напихаем - авось влезет.

Comment: @akina, действительно, не думаю, что файл будет настолько большой, чтоб не влезть в String, который вмещает примерно 2.2 млрд символов. Тем не менее предполагаю, что это просто академическая задача, которую предполагалось решить именно таким способом, а именно, итерируясь по строкам и в цикле инкрементируя счетчик для каждого подходящего символа каждой строки.

Comment: @Tema_Bel точно! практической пользы от моего кода если не совсем нет то очень мало, я выдумываю себе задачу и потом мучаюсь в поиске решения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для проверки конца файла необходимо вместо `scanner.nextLine() != null` надо использовать `scanner.hasNext()`.

Если можно использовать Java8, то я бы сделал следующую реализацию:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Roman\\Desktop\\AAA.txt";
    char symbol = readChar();
    int count = calcCharsCount(fileName, symbol);
    System.out.println(count);
}

private static char readChar() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str = reader.readLine();
    return str.charAt(0);
}

private static int calcCharsCount(String fileName, char symbol) throws IOException {
    return (int) Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
        .flatMap(line -> line.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c))
        .filter(s -> s == symbol)
        .count();
}
```